# What is MVVM? How is it useful?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, xaml, mvvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why MVVM and what are it's core benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644453/why-mvvm-and-what-are-its-core-benefits)

I have people giving loads of suggestion on using view model on my apps.I have absoulteley no idea on what it is.Can anyone explain in simple terms What view model is,How to use it,It's benefits.

Answer (score 2):

Try reading this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) written by Josh Smith.

Answer (score 1):

I think [the recording made by Jason Dolinger](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650) is the best walkthrough I've ever seen. He walks through a standard "I am doing winforms programming in WPF" and gradually transforms it into an MVVM design. Very nicely paced and the test code is accessible.

[Direct link to the video file here](http://www.lab49.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Jason_Dolinger_MVVM.wmv)

Answer (score 0):

MVVM is kind of UI pattern which helps you to architect your application based on SOC and layer separation funda.
Altogether you can use MVVM in Silver Light and WPF application.

It will be good if you go through the video suggested by @Tormod