# Should i add mvvm framework to an old project

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm adding a window to an old project. (10 years+ age) should i make the window consistent with the other old windows or create the new page MVVM style?

There are some bad attempts at MVVM already in the project. Along with some attempts at resource dictionaries ect.

My worry is making an MVVM window that makes it harder for the other devs. The last time i asked this I was greeted with both positive and negative responses from other devs on the project.

what are some solid positives for making it MVVM so i can put the points across to any nay sayers?

Comment: Is the SOC where someone else would design the View?

Comment: sorry im a little unsure what you mean by that

Comment: Then you are going to have trouble selling this to other devs.

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644453/why-mvvm-and-what-are-its-core-benefits) for benefits of mvvm

Comment: Whichever is better.