# How Do I Update/Save Stepper Value for Later Use?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a single window application, basically a calculator, where I can change individual entries on the fly to generate a new profit/break-even answer based on the new price/weight etc. just entered. Each entry view is bound to a stepper value for quick small adjustments or the entry can be edited for big changes. How do I save the value, that the stepper is currently on, for use the next time the application is used??

```
            <Grid x:Name="PurchasePriceGrid">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=".6*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Text="Purchase Price" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="0,0,25,0" Scale="1.2" TranslationX="15" 
                   Grid.Column="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" />
                <customentry:MyEntry x:Name="PurchasePriceEntry" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference PurchasePriceStepper}, Path=Value, FallbackValue=0}"
                                 TextColor="DarkSlateGray" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Ivory" TranslationX="10"
                                 Grid.Column="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Keyboard="Numeric" VerticalOptions="End" MaxLength="5"
                                 TextChanged="PurchasePriceEntry_Completed" />
                <Stepper x:Name="PurchasePriceStepper" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  Scale=".7" TranslationX="3"
                     Maximum="5" Minimum=".01" Increment=".01" Value="1.75" />
            </Grid>
```

I don't want to have to go through each entry and change the values to get back to where I left off every time I open the application, as it does now... I am new to programming and I can't find any example of this for me to follow. I'm guessing I need to somehow use something like  INotifyPropertyChanged  like here [Xamarin Forms - update a label value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761627/xamarin-forms-update-a-label-value) and if so how do I do that with a stepper value? Or is there a better way to get my desired result???

Comment: I just realized you wanted this for xamarin forms, not winforms. You can save values for later by using Application.Current.Properties. This has already been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266797/how-to-store-app-settings-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: You want to save the value in entry before you leave this app? And show the value next time you open the app?

Comment: Jack Hua. The entry view gets its content from the binded stepper value, so the stepper value is what I am needing to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/) and specifically [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android) class.

As I understood, you want to save `PurchasePriceStepper.Value` in a way to retrieve it when you reopen the application.

You can save this value with the following code:

```
Preferences.Set("PurchasePriceStepper", PurchasePriceStepper.Value);
```

You can retrieve your saved value with the following code:

```
var stepperValue = Preferences.Get("PurchasePriceStepper", String.Empty);
```

Keep in mind that you must perform the save of the values on app exit, or in stepper [ValueChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.stepper.valuechanged?view=xamarin-forms) event and the values load maybe in the `onAppearing` event of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save a value before you exit from app and show when you launch the app again you can use `Xamarin.Essentials` NuGet and the "Prefrences".