# Resource dictionary vs extending classes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary

I have been watching some online xamarin forms tutorials. All of them suggest using the resource dictionary for global rules such as styles. However I have noticed a lot of risks of mistakes. Consider the following example:

In the dictionary I mention

```
<Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="lblStyle">
    <Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30" />
</Style>
```

Then I can use it as

```
<Label Text="My Text" Style="{StaticResource lblStyle}" />
```

However when assigning to the dictionary, I only get intellisense some key words and when implementing on the label I don't get intellisense for the key `lblStyle`. Also I don't know if I have entered anything wrong as it is mostly not caught in compile time. I do understand why no intellisense, but I found the following easier to code and it does the same

First I create a class

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    public MyLabel()
    {
        FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold;
        FontSize = 30;
    }

}
```

I can then declare in xml and use following:

```
<Components:MyLabel Text="My Text" />
```

In terms of coding, the second way seems to be better in every way. What I do not understand is, why all the tutorials recommend we use the resource dictionary? Is there some serious performance advantage that is worth all the weak typing?

Comment: It's not about performance, it's about separation of concerns. Classes are for code, XAML is for UI. It has a lot of benefits - the main three are Maintainability, Testability and Blendability.

Comment: Ok, I get your UI separation point but I didn't get any of the three benefits. 
How can it be maintainable if for each change I need to look up and copy paste the property & values? How is there a difference in testability or blendability when both can be called in the same way?

Comment: Tha'ts too long for a comment, and currently I don't have the time to write a good answer.  You can start by reading [this question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644453/why-mvvm-and-what-are-its-core-benefits).

Comment: Just want to mention that performance is impacted here. The static resource lays in memory once and can be reused all the time. This safes a lot of performance in the long run especially when it comes to many controls and styles. Also this can be used for theming (switching the complete style of an app).

Comment: well regarding the performance impact, I did think of that. But for that I can always create a static readonly style variables which would even have a better performance than a dictionary with key value pairs. The theme can still be done. If needed, all classes could even go into the same file.

Comment: Strange - I DO get intellisense for the key lblStyle

Comment: you are getting intellisense for a dictionary's key? That is really strange. Where have you saved your resource dictionary?

Comment: I never hard code font sizes - I define a size say LargeFont of 30 in the dictionary then refer to that from labels etc also in the dictionary. If the customer asks to change the font to 28 I can do it in one place.

Comment: I save my resource dictionary  in app.xaml

Comment: what version of vs? enterprise?

Comment: VS2015 Professional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156240/discussion-between-steve-chadbourne-and-neville-nazerane).